# How to make autoscrolling on if in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a chat in PHP/JS/JQuery and I want autoscroll after new message appears. Here's my code(javascript):

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('submit','#chatForm',function(){
    var text = $.trim($("#text").val());
    var name = $.trim($("#name").val());

    if(text != "" && name != ""){
        $.post('poster.php',{text: text, name: name},function(data){
            $(".chatMessages").append(data);
        });
    }else{
        alert("Data missing!");
    }
});

function getMessages(){
    $.get('receive.php',function(data){
        $(".chatMessages").html(data);
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    getMessages();
    document.getElementById( 'chatBottom' ).scrollIntoView();
},500);
});
```

But it does not scroll

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Does `chatBottom` exist as an `ID`?

Comment: It exists, but don't work. No errors

Comment: Where does it exist? In HTML markup hard-coded into the page? In the `getMessages()` response? It might not be accessible due to scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery animate function like this: `$(".chatMessages).animate({scrollTop:$(this).scrollHeight},500);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something as below -

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

You might not need the `setTimeout` function here, but have to check for a new message everytime.